# Valid/Invalid Parameter pass

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, sqlplus

Can someone explain what login exactly applies for parameter pass with `>=` sign for varchar columns?

## Code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_dept ( p_name

departments.department_name%TYPE DEFAULT .unknown ., p_loc

departments.location_id%TYPE DEFAULT 1700) IS BEGIN INSERT INTO

departments(department_id, department_name, loclation_id)

VALUES(dept_seq.NEXTVAL,p_name, p_loc); END add_dept; / You created the add_dept procedure above, and you now invoke the procedure in SQL *Plus.
```

## Question

Which four are valid invocations? (Choose four)

A. EXECUTE add_dept(p_loc=>2500)

B. EXECUTE add_dept(‘Education’, 2500)

C. EXECUTE add_dept(‘2500′, p_loc =>2500)

D. EXECUTE add_dept(p_name=>’Education’, 2500)

E. EXECUTE add_dept(p_loc=>2500, p_name=>’Education’)

Comment: stack overflow is not here to answer your test question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: This would also be much easier to answer if you formatted your code.

Comment: The section of the manual you are looking for is [Positional, Named, and Mixed Notation for Actual Parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/subprograms.htm#LNPLS00825).

Comment: @TomLous : I came across this question and didn't knew why D was invalid

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the fact that it is really easy to test, I don't know why didn't you do it yourself.

I've fixed typos you've made (what would `.unknown.` be? Dots?) and removed unnecessary part of the procedure, and the result is as follows. Oracle answers your question (i.e. what's wrong with an invalid procedure call).

```
SQL> create or replace procedure add_dept
  2    (p_name dept.dname%type default 'unknown',
  3     p_loc  dept.deptno%type default 99)
  4  is
  5  begin
  6    null;
  7  end;
  8  /

Procedure created.

SQL> -- A
SQL> EXECUTE add_dept(p_loc=>2500);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> -- B
SQL> EXECUTE add_dept('Education', 2500);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> -- C
SQL> EXECUTE add_dept('2500', p_loc =>2500);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> -- D
SQL> EXECUTE add_dept(p_name=>'Education', 2500);
BEGIN add_dept(p_name=>'Education', 2500); END;

                                    *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 37:
PLS-00312: a positional parameter association may not follow a named association
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored


SQL>
SQL> -- E
SQL> EXECUTE add_dept(p_loc=>2500, p_name=>'Education');

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks, appreciate your time.